# In the div, i have placed a one word text. It is mysteriously getting unwanted space and I cannot understand why it comes

Tags: html, css, django

I am trying to build a portfolio website using Django. I have created a template with the following HTML code:

However, on minimizing the browser, I notice that it aligns to the left perfectly.

```css
    .div-title{
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    .experience-container{
        min-height: 100px;
        height: fit-content;
        width: 300px;
        margin-left: 50px;
        padding: 10px;
        
        transition: all 0.5s;
        border-radius: 10px;

        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px; 
        
        box-shadow: 0px 5px rgb(162, 162, 163);

    }

    .experience-container:hover{
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 30px rgb(255, 0, 0);  
        
    }

    .experience-div{
       margin: auto;

        
    }


.project-container{
    min-height: 100px;
    height: fit-content;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    /* border: 1px solid rgb(63, 61, 61); */
    transition: all 0.5s;
    border-radius: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
    
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-top: 50px; 
}

.project-container:hover{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px orange;
}

.project-div{
    padding-left:  10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    height: fit-content;
    min-height: 760px;
    
}
.image-for-project-container{
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Project" class="bg-white fnt-white brdr project-div ">
    <div class="float-left image-for-project-container brdr">
        <img src="{% static './Images/manworking.webp' %}" alt="manworking"  height="700px">
    </div>

    
    {% for project in project_details %}
    
    
    <div class=" project-container inline-block brdr">
        <h2 class="text-center fnt-black head-portfolio">
            {{project.project_name}}
        </h2>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p class="margin-auto txt-portfolio roboto hover-orange fnt-black">
            {{project.project_details}}
        </p>
        <br>
        <a href="#" class="buttons read-more fnt-black">Read More</a>  
    </div>
    
    {% endfor %}
    
    
    
</div>

<div class="bg-black fnt-white experience-div block brdr">
        
        <h1 class="brdr block div-title roboto fnt-orange roboto">
            Education
        </h2>

        <div class="experience-container inline-block bg-gray">
            <h2 class="text-center fnt-black head-portfolio">
                Lorem, ipsum.
            </h2>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p class="margin-auto txt-portfolio roboto  fnt-black">
                Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero nemo dolore sit perferendis qui ad hic, expedita, magnam ipsam est eligendi nulla, ipsum quasi fuga?Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi corrupti asperiores voluptatem sit fugiat saepe doloribus suscipit rerum eum. Nulla molestiae quasi sint libero voluptate qui repellat quis eos ratione itaque! Aut deserunt labore excepturi corporis hic nostrum voluptates vero beatae facilis non amet quaerat aliquam iste eveniet natus, voluptatem aperiam veritatis, expedita incidunt quis sunt eaque saepe est totam.
            </p>
            <br>
            <a href="#" class="buttons read-more fnt-white">Read More</a>
            
        </div>
    </div>
```

I do believe these are the relevant CSS which could make a difference, but if any more is required please do let me know. Thanks!

Additionally, please do explain why your solution is required and what I have done wrong if you can. :)

For reference, I have attached an Image:

[image: The unexpected indentation picture]

Comment: you want the `Education` to be aligned left?

Comment: Without a [mcve] that contains the css and html that allows the reproduce the problem it is not possible to tell what you do wrong.

Comment: It looks look as if `text-align` is set to  `center` for the `h1` element, but there are to few information in the question.

Comment: @t.niese I believe it should be reproducible now? I have tried to only include relevant CSS classes, since my entire CSS file isn't organized. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: @SasidharBoddeti Yes, I do. But you can see in the image that there is an unexpected gap, I want it to be a subheading for the education divfor my portfolio website.

Comment: @AfifMohammedVarikkodan As you can see when you click "Run code snippet", "Education" is aligned left. So you still haven't posted a reproducible example.

Comment: @aaron I have copy-pasted my entire code and it still does not produce a reproducible example. I believe the only issue I can identify is the image that I have inserted which uses a float-left. Is there some condition to be met when using float-left

Comment: @AfifMohammedVarikkodan Nope. How about sharing a repro project on GitHub?

Comment: @aaron i do not know how to. I changed the display of my image from float-left to inline block and it is working alright. I believe it has something to do with float.

Comment: See https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/hello-world.